# Adding asp.net control tags to an XML schema file

Tags: asp.net, xml, xsd, xhtml

I have an xsd that describes XHTML documents. However the application I'm working with may have some selected asp.net controls within to the markup at the point is validated. Therefore the validation fails.

An example control could be:

```
<smart:Address runat="server" />
```

I wanted to add a new element to the xsd file but when I specify:

```
<xs:element name="smart:Address">
```

I get validation errors as an element name must not have a colon in it.

Can anyone suggest how I might be able to extend the schema file to allow selected server controls?

**Update**
To help things along the full xsd is available at:
[xhtml1-transistional.xsd](http://www.digital-rant.co.uk/xhtml1-transitional.xsd)

Comment: Have you seen xml namespaces?

Answer (score 2):

You're missing that "smart" is an XML namespace.

In other words: you need to declare "smart" namespace:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:smart="http://someurl" ......
```

Learn more here:

- http://www.learn-xml-schema-tutorial.com/Namespaces.cfm

Comment: No, you need to declare the XML namespace (xmlns:smart) in your existing schema element :)

Comment: I've tried adding a second namesapce but when I add the ref attribute for a new xs:element I get a warning saying it is not allowed.

Comment: I don't know how's your XSD, but visual editors don't have the final word. Just try to validate with your XSD and see if it works like expected.

Comment: Unfortunately not when I try and validate I get 'name attribute required'. If I add one then I get 'the ref attribute cannot be present'. 

I will post the full xsd above.

Comment: I don't see there the "smart" namespace declaration :O

Comment: No I've removed it because the error. If you try and add it you will get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the element declarations for the smart namespace in a separate schema document, whose targetNamespace attribute identifies the namespace. The name attribute of constructs like xs:element and xs:simpleType is always an unqualified (local) name, implicitly qualified by the targetNamespace (use elementFormDefault="qualified" to ensure this is true even for local element declarations). When you refer to an element declaration in one schema document from a component in a different schema document, then (a) you must have an xs:import declaration to indicate the dependency, and (b) you use a qualified name for the reference, in the form prefix:local, where prefix is bound to the corresponding namespace using an xmlns:prefix="uri" declaration, usually on the xs:schema element.